# Java generics and type synonyms

Tags: java, generics, types

I was considering implementing something like `interface Dto<K, V> extends Map<K, V> {}` but what I really wanted to express is that `Dto<K, V>` is a type synonym for `Map<K, V> {}` like you can do in Haskell http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Type_synonym to improve the readability of code.

Is this possible to express in Java or should I use the Map interface directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, Java provides no way to define a synonym.

Generics however do provide some of the expressiveness of synonyms. The parameterized type (e.g. the "V"), indicates the type of object.

```
Map<Sting, Dto> dtoMap = ...
```

This is clearly a map of Sting->Dto.

The topic of extending a built-in type purely for renaming is considered by some to be an anti-pattern.  Although this is a debated topic.  See: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/246277/good-or-bad-practice-to-mask-java-collections-with-meaningful-class-names.

Comment: Yes now I see this is a an anti-pattern: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02216/index.html